# Can mobs break down wooden doors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

acacia door to be specific . it looks very easy to break ( sorry guys I'm a noob I started yesterday ) I haven't waited to see yet because I only have a wooden sword at the moment and i don't want to be killed i collect a lot and built a nice house

Answer (score 4):

The mobs that can only break your door are a Zombie or a Creeper.
The Zombie will only break your door if your gamedifficulty is on 'Hard' and the creeper will always break your wooden door if it explodes nearby.

Hope that it helped